# How to calculate token ID for my own NFT marketplace

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, mining, nft, erc-721

I am just creating my own NFT marketplace.
I need to create unique token ID for each NFT but the current demo for token ID is like below.

```
contract ERC721 {
  ...
  mapping(uint256 => address) private _tokenOwners;

  function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenID) {
    _tokenOwner[tokenID] = to;
    ...
  }
}

contract CryptoDog is ERC721 {
    ...
  string[] public cryptoDogz;  

  function mint(string memory nftName) public {

    cryptoDogz.push(ntfName);
    uint256 _tokenID = cryptoDogz.length - 1;
    _mint(msg.sender, _tokenID);
    ...
    
  }
}
```

I will appreciate it if you provide me with a way to generate uniquely token ID.

Comment: Hi there. Do you mean "unique" or "random"? Doesn't the code above generate you a unique ID?

Comment: It is set up to the length of token array. 
The contract address(public key) is a unique hash value. I mean such unique number for token ID.

Comment: But if the size of the token array only ever increases (during the NFT sale), then each new token will have a unique ID based on the array length. (i.e. Each ID will be different.)

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter to start from ID 1, and increment it when you mint new NFTs. You will get a different and incremental number for each NFT. You can use this code from [OpenZeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc721):

```
// contracts/GameItem.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract GameItem is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("GameItem", "ITM") {}

    function awardItem(address player, string memory tokenURI)
        public
        returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(player, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        _tokenIds.increment();
        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

The example is using the [Counters library from OpenZeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils#Counters).

You can check how it is implemented [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Counters.sol).

Comment: If the answer helps, you are welcome to vote up this answer as correct.

Comment: Sorry but I should have at least 15 reputations to cast a vote for your answer. I am a newbie here.